# Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I put a event of tapped in this Item Control to see the image when I tap the image, but when I do I receive this error what I to do to fix it. I try to change to Item Image but didn't exist.

XAML Code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icPareoExerciseControl1" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding lstPareoItem}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExercisePareoDataTemplate2}"
  Foreground="Black" Width="400" 
  Margin="100,0,0,0" 
  Tapped="inlineImage_Tapped"/>
```

Code:

```
   private void inlineImage_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
       {
          Image temp = (Image)sender;
          if (temp.DataContext is MultimediaElement)
          {



          }
        else
        {
            Image ImageToGrid = (Image)sender;
            ImageContent myImage = new ImageContent();
            myImage.ImgUri = ImageToGrid.Source.ToString();
            ImageSource imgSource = ImageToGrid.Source;
            gridGallery.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            stckImageMenuGallery.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ImageGalleryUri = (imgSource as BitmapImage).UriSource.OriginalString;
            imgPopup.Source = ImageToGrid.Source;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Tapped` routed event is bound to the `ItemsControl`, not to the `Image`.

That results in this line failing:

```
Image temp = (Image)sender;
```

In this case that should have been:

```
ItemsControl temp = (ItemsControl)sender;
```

Alter your code so it binds to the `Image` you are creating in your `ItemsControl`. Then the first cast will work.

Comment: So how can I fix that? I spouse to put in the binding?

Comment: @user3604503: Put the `Tapped=...` on the `Image`.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @user3604503: That seems logical since the two are not the same type. What are you trying to do?